# get specific word from one column in select query

Tags: string, split, mapping

I have column in table with below data and I would like to get a single word from this string excluding special character and Number.

Below is my table data
90% Polyester- Polyurethane coated, 8% Cotton - Polyurethane coated, 2% Viscose - Polyurethane coated

Output needed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLJLH.png)
Polyester- Polyurethane coated
Cotton - Polyurethane coated
Viscose - Polyurethane coated

After getting this output have to combine the same after mapping it to another tables data.